# DownloadFileAsync throw Get TimeOut exception

Tags: c#, flurl

I have put Flurl in high load using `DownloadFileAsync` method to download files in private network from one server to another and after several hours the method starts to throw exceptions "Get TimeOut". The only solution to solve that is restart application.

```
downloadUrl.DownloadFileAsync(Helper.CreateTempFolder()).Result;
```

I have added second method as failover using HTTPClient and its download files fine after flurl fails, so it is not server problem.

```
private void DownloadFile(string fileUri, string locationToStoreTo)
       {
           using (var client = new HttpClient())
           using (var response = client.GetAsync(new Uri(fileUri)).Result)
           {
               response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

               var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

               using (var fileStream = File.Create(locationToStoreTo))
               {
                   stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
               }
           }
       }
```

Do you have any idea why Get TimeOut error starts popup on high load using the method?

```
public static Task<string> DownloadFileAsync(this string url, string localFolderPath, string localFileName = null, int bufferSize = 4096, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

The two download code differ only that **Flurl** re-use `HttpClient` instance for all request and my code destroy and create new HttpClient object for every new request. I know that creating and destroying HttpClient is time and resource consuming I rather would use Flurl if it would work.

Comment: Don't block on async calls with `.Result`. Make `DownloadFile` async instead of void and then `await` everything.

Comment: "I know that creating and destroying HttpClient is time and resource consuming" - You could use static `HttpClient`. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330364/should-we-create-a-new-single-instance-of-httpclient-for-all-requests

Comment: @AnkitVijay using a static instance will not pick up DNS changes, so should not be used for long running programs. If the reason Flurl starts failing is because it's re-using an HttpClient that has an old IP address cached, then using a static HttpClient will have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @zivkan DNS issues can be mitigated by setting a [timeout on the connection lease](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint.connectionleasetimeout?view=netframework-4.7.2). I would bet just about anything the problem is simply a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

As others point out, you're trying to use Flurl synchronously by calling `.Result`. This is not supported, and under highly concurrent workloads you're most likely witnessing deadlocks.

The `HttpClient` solution is using a new instance for every call, and since instances aren't shared at all it's probably less prone to deadlocks. But it's inviting a whole new problem: [port exhaustion](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

In short, if you want to continue using Flurl then go ahead and do so, especially since you're getting smart `HttpClient` reuse "for free". Just use it asynchronously (with `async`/`await`) as intended. See the [docs](https://flurl.io) for more information and examples.

Comment: I do not understand how not using Asynchronous could produce deadlock. I don't need Asynchronous because I do not run any code in parallel. I want to run coder step by step in that thread. If I recall correctly the HttpClient.GetAsync is thread safe method. I suppose Flurl DownloadFileAsync use HttpClient.GetAsync under the hood.

Comment: Yes, `DownloadFileAsync` is making asynchronous calls under the hood. So it's not exactly correct to say you're "not using asynchronous" and more accurate to say you're _blocking_ on async calls. [Don't do that](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Use `await` instead of `.Result`. Even if you don't think you need it, it's just as easy, it eliminates the possibility of deadlocks, it massively improves the thread efficiency of your app, it it will scale much better should you want to introduce concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two or three possibilities (I'm sure there are others that I can't think of as well)

1. Server IP address has changed.

You wrote that Flurl reuses a HttpClient. I've never used, or even heard of Flurl, so I have no idea how it works. But an HttpClient re-uses a pool of connections, which is why it's efficient to reuse a single instance and why it's critical to do so in a high-volume microservice application, otherwise you're likely to exhaust all ports, but that gives a different error message, not a time out, so I know you haven't hit that case. However, while it's important to re-use an HttpClient in the short term, HttpClient will cache DNS results, which means it's important to dispose and create new HttpClients periodically. In short-lived processes, you can use a static or singleton instance. But in long running processes, you should create a new instance periodically. If you only use it to access one server, that server's DNS TTL is a good value to use.

So, what might be happening is the server changed IP addresses a few hours after your program started, and because Flurl keep reusing the same HttpClient, it doesn't get the new IP address from the DNS entry. One way to check if this is the problem is write the server's IP address to a log at the beginning of the process and when you encounter the problem, check if the IP address is the same or not.

If this is the problem, you can look into ASP.NET Core 2.1's HttpClientFactory. It's a bit awkward to use outside of ASP.NET, but I did once. It gives you re-use of HttpClients, to avoid the TCP port exhaustion problem of using more than 32k HttpClients in 120 seconds, but also avoid DNS caching issues. My memory is that it creates a new HttpClient every 5 minutes by default.

2. Reaching the maximum connections per server

[ServicepointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=netframework-4.7.2) sets the maximum number of HTTP connections that a client will open to a server. If your code tries to use more than this simultaneously, the requests that exceed the limit will wait for an existing HTTP client to finish its request, then it will use the newly available connection. However, in the past when I was looking into this, the HTTP timeout started from when the HttpClient's method was called, not when the HttpClient sends the request to the server over a connection. This means that if your limit is 2 and both are used for longer than the timeout period (for example if downloading 2 large files), other requests to download from the same server will time out, even though no http request was ever sent to the server.

So, depending on your application and server, you may be able to use a higher connection limit, otherwise you need to implement request queuing in your app.

3. Thread pool exhaustion

Async code is awesome for performance when used correctly in highly concurrent, IO bound workloads. I sometimes think it's a bad idea to use anywhere else because it such huge potential for causing weird problems when used incorrectly. Like Crowcoder wrote in a comment on the question, you shouldn't use `.Result`, or any code that blocks a running thread, when in an async context. Although the code sample you provided says `public void DownloadFile(...` , if it's actually `public async Task DownloadFile(...`, or if `DownloadFile` is called from an async method, then there's real risk of issues. If DownloadFile is not called from an async method, but is called on the thread pool, there's the same risk of errors.

Understanding async is a huge topic, unfortunately with a lot of misinformation on the internet as well, so I can't possibly cover it in detail here. A key thing to note is that async tasks run on the thread pool. So, if you call `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` and block the thread that your code runs on, or if you have async tasks that you block on (for example by calling .Result), what could happen is that you block every thread in the thread pool, and when an HTTP response comes back from the network, the .NET run time has no threads available to complete the task. The problem with this idea is that there are also no threads available to signal the timeout, so I don't believe you're exhausting the thread pool (if you were, I would expect a deadlock), but I don't know how timeouts are implemented. If timeouts/timers use a dedicated thread it could be possible for a cancellation token (the thing that signals a timeout) to be set by the timer's thread, and then any code on a blocking wait for either the HTTP response or the cancellation token could be triggered. But thread pool exhaustion generally causes deadlocks, so if you're getting an error back, it's probably not this.

To check if you're having threadpool exhaustion issues, when your program starts getting the timeout errors, get a memory dump of your app (for example using Task Manager). If you have the Enterprise or Ultimate SKU of Visual Studio, you can open/debug the memory dump in VS. Otherwise you'll need to learn how to use windbg (or find another tool). When debugging the memory dump, check the number of threads. If there's a very large number of threads, that's a hint you might be on the right track. Check where the thread was at the time of the memory dump. If they're all in blocking calls like WaitForObject, or something similar, then there's a real risk you've exhausted the thread pool. I've never debugged an async task deadlock/thread pool exhaustion issue before, so I'm not sure if there's a way to get a list of tasks and see from their runstate if they're likely to be deadlocked or not. If you ever see more tasks in the running state than you have cores on your CPU, you almost certainly have blocking in an async task, however.

In summary, you haven't given us enough details to give you an answer that will work with 100% certainty. You need to keep investigating to understand the problem until you can either solve it yourself, or provide us with more information. I've given you some of the most likely causes, but it could very easily be something else completely.